# Fetching Data from Database Issue in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-layout

I have three layout:

1. Main Layout(with a button "Profile")
2. Profile layout(With textview to show data from database and two button named as "Edit" and "Back to Main")
3. Edit layout(With textview and edittext to edit the profile of the user and two button again that says "Save" and "back to profile")

Methods Related to Buttons:
(Button are with one star,related methods are with two stars)

*Profile: **editm(View w)

*Edit: **calledit(View w)

*Back to main: **backmain(View w)

**Save:**savemethj(View w)

*back to profile: **pbackmeth(View w)

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity
   {
    TextView t1;
EditText e1,e2;
   databasehelper helper; 
       //Profile variables
      String ptrm;
pdatabasehelper phelper;
EditText ed1;
EditText ed2;
EditText ed3;
EditText ed4;
EditText ed5;
EditText ed6;
TextView ptn;
TextView kt0;
TextView kt1;
TextView kt2;
TextView kt3;TextView kt4;TextView kt5;TextView kt6;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     phelper=new pdatabasehelper(this);
}
     public void backmain(View w){ 
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }
     public void editm(View w){ 
setContentView(R.layout.profilec);
          try{
                      pshow();
}
catch(Exception e){ 
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "pshow method", 5).show();
}



    }


public void pshow()
{
    onStartp();
    Log.d("7", "a");
    onstart();

    Log.d("10", "a");
    try{
        Log.d("55555", "entering to db");
       Cursor c=phelper.pshowrecord(ptrm);
       Log.d("11", "a");
       if (c!=null){

           Log.d("c1", "a");
           c.moveToFirst();

           Log.d("cmm1", "a");
        String name= c.getString(0);
           Log.d("cn1", "a");
                  kt1.setText(name);
                                  Log.d("c2", "a");
        kt2.setText(c.getString(1));
        Log.d("c3", "a");

        kt3.setText(c.getString(2));
        Log.d("12", "a");
        kt4.setText(c.getString(3));
        kt5.setText(c.getString(4));
        kt6.setText(c.getString(5));
        Log.d("13", "a");
        }
    else{
        Log.d("14", "a");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Add a Contact", 50).show(); 
    }
        }catch(Exception e){ 
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SOme display error", 20).show();
    }
}


public void pbackmeth(View w){

    setContentView(R.layout.profilec);
    pshow();
}
public void calledit(View w)
{

        setContentView(R.layout.editc);


}

public void onStartp(){ 
    kt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext3);
    kt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext5);
    kt3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext7);
    kt4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext9);
    kt5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext11);
    kt6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext13);
}

public void onstart(){ 

     ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jname);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText1);
      ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText2);
      ed4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText3);
      ed5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText4);
     ed6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jaeditText1);
      ptn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jprofile);

}

public void savemethj(View w)
{ 

    onstart();
    Log.d("tag000", "before allgettext");

    long a;
    Log.d("tag01111", "afterlong");
    ptrm=ptn.getText().toString();
    try{ 
    phelper.deleterecord(ptrm);
    Log.d("tag02222", "be");
    String edt1=ed1.getText().toString();
    String edt2=ed2.getText().toString();
    Log.d("tag03333", "be11111");
    String edt3=ed3.getText().toString();
    String edt4=ed4.getText().toString();
    Log.d("tag0444444", "be2222");
    String edt5=ed5.getText().toString();
    String edt6=ed6.getText().toString();
    Log.d("tag11111", "after allgettext");

     phelper.deleterecord(ptrm);
    a=phelper.insertpro(ptrm,/*img*/edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4, edt5, edt6);
    Log.d("tag9999999", "after allgettext");

    if(a>=1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),a+ "Record Successfully Saved", 30).show();
    }

    else{

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Not Saved", 30).show();

    }}
    catch(Exception e)
    { 

       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Errrrrrrrrrrr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    }
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Database class :

```
   public class pdatabasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
final static String databasename="demonewexp";
final static int databaseversion=1;

public pdatabasehelper(Context ctx){
     super(ctx,databasename,null,databaseversion);

    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{

         Log.d("tag4545","database");   
   db.execSQL("create table mypro(id text,name text,guardian text,number text,address text,medical text,another text)");

    }
    catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("drop table if Exists mypro");
    onCreate(db);

}



 public long insertpro(String id,String e1,String e2,String e3,String e4,String e5,String e6)
 {
    SQLiteDatabase base=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put("id", id);
    value.put("name", e1);
    value.put("guardian", e2);
    value.put("number", e3);
    value.put("address", e4);
    value.put("medical", e5);
    value.put("another", e6);

    long a=base.insert("mypro",null,value);

     return a;
 }
 public Cursor pshowrecord(String id)
    {
     Log.d("d1", "a");
        Cursor cs = null;
        SQLiteDatabase base=getReadableDatabase();
        Log.d("d2", "a");
        try
        {
            Log.d("d3", "a");
         cs=base.query("mypro", new String[]{"name","guardian","number","address","medical","another"},"id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
         Log.d("d4", "a");
         return cs;
        }catch(Exception e){ 
            Log.d("d5", "a");
            return cs;
        }


    }


 public void deleterecord(String pe_id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase base=getWritableDatabase();
        base.delete("mypro","id=?",new String[]{pe_id});
    }

          }
```

I Start my application 1st time,I clicked the "profile" button,there is no data therefore it shows toast like "some display error" then i click edit button and add the data like name,number etc click save button,it get saved. then i move back to profile layout by clicking "back to profile" and i can see my added profile or data. then if i move back to main layout by clicking "back to main" and if again i click 
"profile" button then it also take me to the profile layout with added data that was fetched everytime from database. But here it come the problem when i close my application
and start it again i click "profile" button,then its not showing anything even database values were there in database but when i start my app again it is unable to fetch the data that i have previously stored and showing toast like "some display error". I thought to check out the errors and put some "Log" then i see log file when i was working with application then it is showing last value as:

```
    Log.d("cmm1", "a");
```

After that my application stopped and no logs generated in log file. That means i get error while i was working with:

```
     String name= c.getString(0);
```

I dont know what is the problem with this code or may be i have any other problem. Please help me out. Am i missing something?

k I have edited the code with intent to start new Activity. I have other code too but cut paste the code to make it easy to view and find error. Here is my code now:

(1st Activity with button  Profile,clicking profile button take to another activity with intent)

MainActivity.class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);phelper=new pdatabasehelper(this);
     }

 public void editm(View w){ 

      Intent pro=new Intent(MainActivity.this,profile.class);
      startActivity(new Intent(pro));

             }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
  }
```

(to show profile)

profile.class:

```
    public class profile extends Activity
    {
pdatabasehelper phelper;
TextView ptn;
TextView kt0;
TextView kt1;
TextView kt2;
TextView kt3;TextView kt4;TextView kt5;TextView kt6;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Profile View", 5).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.profilec);
    Log.d("oncreate5", "5");
    ptn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jprofile);
    Log.d("oncreate5.666", "5.6");
    phelper=new pdatabasehelper(this);
    Log.d("oncreate5", "6");
    pshow();
    Log.d("oncreate5", "7");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "helloo new", 10).show();

}

public void pshow(){
    Log.d("6", "a");
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "helloo new", 10).show();
    onStartp();
    Log.d("7", "a");
    Cursor c=null;
    Log.d("8", "a");

    Log.d("9,10", "a");
    try{
        Log.d("55555", "entering to db");
    String ptrm = null;
    c=phelper.pshowrecord(ptrm);
    Log.d("11", "a");


    if(c!=null){
          Log.d("c1", "a");
           c.moveToFirst();

             Log.d("cmm1", "a");
        String name= c.getString(0);
            Log.d("cn1", "a");
            kt1.setText(name);
                Log.d("c2", "a");
        kt2.setText(c.getString(1));
        Log.d("c3", "a");

        kt3.setText(c.getString(2));
        Log.d("12", "a");
        kt4.setText(c.getString(3));
        kt5.setText(c.getString(4));
        kt6.setText(c.getString(5));
        Log.d("13", "a");
        c.close();
        Log.d("14", "a");

}
    else{

        Toast.makeText(this,"Add a Contact", 50).show(); 
    }
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SOme display error", 20).show();
    }
}




public void calledit(View w)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,editp.class);
    startActivity(i);
        //setContentView(R.layout.editc);


}


public void onStartp(){ 
    kt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext3);
    kt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext5);
    kt3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext7);
    kt4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext9);
    kt5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext11);
    kt6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext13);
}

}
```

(To add or edit the profile with save button)
editp.class

```
     public class editp extends Activity {

EditText ed1;
EditText ed2;
EditText ed3;
EditText ed4;
EditText ed5;
EditText ed6;
TextView ptn;

pdatabasehelper phelper;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editc);
    phelper=new pdatabasehelper(this);

}

public void onstart(){ 

     ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jname);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText1);
      ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText2);
      ed4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText3);
      ed5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText4);
     ed6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jaeditText1);
      ptn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jprofile);
}


public void savemethj(View w)
{ 

    onstart();
    Log.d("tag000", "before allgettext");

    long a;
    Log.d("tag01111", "afterlong");
    String ptrm = ptn.getText().toString();
    try{ 
    phelper.deleterecord(ptrm);
    Log.d("tag02222", "be");
    String edt1=ed1.getText().toString();
    String edt2=ed2.getText().toString();
    Log.d("tag03333", "be11111");
    String edt3=ed3.getText().toString();
    String edt4=ed4.getText().toString();
    Log.d("tag0444444", "be2222");
    String edt5=ed5.getText().toString();
    String edt6=ed6.getText().toString();
    Log.d("tag11111", "after allgettext");

     phelper.deleterecord(ptrm);
    a=phelper.insertpro(ptrm,edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4, edt5, edt6);

    if(a>=1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),a+ "Record Successfully Saved", 30).show();
    }

    else{

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Not Saved", 30).show();

    }}
    catch(Exception e)
    { 

       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Errrrrrrrrrrr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    }

  }
```

My records are saved in database i can see them,But i am unable to look at those records in the profile that i have saved first time even i called pshow() to fetch out the record from database. I want everytime i come to profile i can see those records either moving back from edit page or clicking "profile" button on main page or layout.
please help me to find error. and excuse the Log commands that i have put to see the errors. and moreover i am getting error here:

```
  String name= c.getString(0);
```

because last Log i see while running program in log file is:

```
    Log.d("cmm1", "a");
```

After that error message displayed on the screen with toast like "some display error".

Comment: I see several problems... You first need to understand the Android activity lifecycle. Then you need to study up on "Intents". developer.android.com is your new favorite website...

Comment: Ok Mr. McKenzie,I will go for it. But Would you please tell me the problem Because i need to complete this code for My School ?

Comment: Biggest Problem is you need to actually start a new activity using an intent instead of changing the content view.

Comment: And you should then use a CursorLoader...

Comment: Actually Our teacher didn't teach us Android lifecycle. Ok i will do that But as i posted i got problem in cursor while fetching the value from database when i start my application again. will it be solve by working with intents or if you can help me to modify this code then it will be time saving for me.

Comment: Showing you is one thing but doing your homework for you is another... I will give you some building blocks and you should be able to get the idea. What version of android are you building for?... Another thing... What is your teacher teaching you if he/she doesn't give you the building blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of work to do really but consider this.
Instead of:

```
public void editm(View w){ 
setContentView(R.layout.profilec);
    try{
        pshow();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "pshow method", 5).show();
    }
}
```

You want:

```
Intent edit_profile_intent = new Intent();
edit_profile_intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), EditProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(edit_profile_intent);
```

So you would need to do several things: Create this new activity class, declare it in your manifest, Edit your layout to include the appropriate views, etc.

Lets fix your activity stack and then worry about your data problems...