# Back Button closes the Application in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Application.Suppose there are three Activities A,B,C.

A->B(Sub-Activity)->C(Sub-Activity).

I have set up these kind code to switch to next activity.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.B);
```

And Problem is When i click back button on emulator or phone while i am on Activity B or C,closes the application window come back to home.
I want that if i will press back button on Activity C it will firstly move to Activity B and then to A,Afterwards if i'll click again to back button then it comes to home-screen or closes application window.

Any methods or something wrong in my code or have to edit ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default back press and tell it you reset your content view but you will have to keep track of the stack yourself.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //code to reset view
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This said I really recommend you look at allow android to handle the stack in the default manner. Your method will end up causing you headaches in the future.

Comment: Yes,I heard about that Overriding back press method but dont know how to use. Moreover is it good to override that method ?

Comment: As long as the user gets the expected result I would say yes it if ok to override.

Comment: However you are changing your view you could simply set a variable to keep track of what view you are on and what view should be seen when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Ok, Mr. Larry.Can you show me how could i implement in my code ?

Comment: Post an example of how you start your new "activity" and I can add to my code example to help you make sense of it.

Comment: Ok,thank you and Do i need any other thing  to keep in mind while working with this Code ?

Comment: I not sure what you mean but by adding this code to your activity you are intercepting the back press so you can do something that the default implementation doesn't do.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thank you :) Between My friend have runtime problem with some code,Would you please help him to get out of it ? We both are newbies to programming.

Comment: I think overriding the back press is a bad usage

Comment: I agree but considering what the OP has asked it is the answer. The best thing is write the app to use the framework as I have already stated...

Comment: Yes,He Did. Actually he posted some wrong format firstly then edited but till then he got 1 negative sign so nobody bothers to look at it. or may be they find lengthy. Here is the link. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628834/fetching-data-from-database-issue-in-android

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie don't you think that if he actually changes activty correctly without setting the content view when he'll press the back button it will go to the activity he were at  as he expect it to do

Comment: Yes I do @Hosni you are absolutely correct. I highly recommend that he do that but if he wishes to continue down his current path overriding back press is the only other option.

Comment: @Mr.Larry and Mr.Hosni-Thank you for this Good conversation. I learned many Basic things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually start a new activity and then set the layout in there for the back button to work. Have a look at [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Just setting the view to a new layout is not the same as starting a new activity. From your code, it appears you're just changing the layout and not starting a new activity.

Comment: Yes,I am not starting the activity. And i just read about life cycle basic methods,Not about the Task and Back Stack.

Comment: Okay, so if you start a new activity and then set the layout in there, the back button will work. If this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Ok,Thanks Mr. Willem. But Is working with intent need attention when i saved data in activity C and displaying it in Activity B. ?? Did you get my question ? Between I am saving data in Database.

Answer (score 0):

As the method `setContentView` says, you are just changing the content view for the **Activity A**. Check [The Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and the method `startActivity` to start new Activity, and read and the [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for more information.

Comment: Ya,I know that. But i thought may be Is there any way to go for the previous activity with phone back button ?

Comment: The phone back button goes to the previous `Activity`, but as I understand for your explanation, you are not changing the Activity. Your application remains in **Activity A** and when you click the bank button there is no more Activities in the `Back Stack`. Check this example about [how to change Activities](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen).

Answer (score 0):

As you're using **setContentView** , you're not switching between activities.

You actually are just changing the content of one and only one activity. Which explains the reason why when you press the back button it closes the application window.

**activity A / content A -> activity A / content B -> activity A / content C**

if you want to go from an activity to another: you should use Intent and startActivity.

for example you implement a button within the onClick function of the button you implement this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i);
```

and in a different Java file named **ActivityTwo.java** you implement a class **ActivityTwo** which extends Activity, within the onCreate method you set a different view, which might be equivalent to **content B**

you're application scheme will be like this:

**activity A / content A -> activity B / content B -> activity C / content C**

When you'll be on activity C and you'll press the back button you'll go to activity B.

Comment: I know about the intent but You Make me Clear that how the actual scenario works. Thank you very much. +1

Comment: Appreciate your help. And If you are free for moment then please look at the code which i have posted the link in @Mr.Larry's comment session.